# How to properly solve the EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_i386_GPFLT) error in my function

Tags: swift, error-handling, uitextfield, runtime-error

Ok, so total Swift noob here. Going through some beginner tutorials.

In order to achieve some goal,

> I need a UITextField to accept only numbers

I have managed to get the UITextField to accept only letters via this code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var TextField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.TextField.delegate = self
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.letters
        let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
        return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet)

    }


}
```

However as soon as I turn `allowedCharacters` into something like:

`let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789")`

The `Simulator` still launches successfully (and I get a `Build Succeeded` message)

However, as soon as I start typing it crashes. Xcode then highlights my `return` statement and shows the error message:

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_i386_GPFLT)`

When I google for it I get the sense that it might have something to do with the fact that I might need to an `if-statement` somewhere in my function to catch any unexpected values that I guess are being returned as soon as I start typing in the textfield, but I can not see the logic yet as to where and how.

Any thoughts to enlighten me would be great!

**PS**: I know I could also just configure my textfield to only show a numpad, but I'd still like to know why the current solution is causing problems for I might need other, more advanced, restrictions sometime in the future.

**EDIT**

Another solution that works (which I discovered after posting the question) is to change my declaration of allowedCharacters as such:

`let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits`

However, the accepted answer to this question allows for more finetuning when necessary.

Comment: why do not you use `number keyboard`?

Comment: @SB87 : JuicyFruit is absolutely correct. Why don't you use number keypad..? It willl allow only a number input.

Comment: @JuicyFruit & anilkukdeja: see the PS of my original question. I suspect I will be needing more advanced selections in the future, so a numpad might do for now but I need to understand how to enforce other selections as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle it that way, instead of making a character set out of your string and checking if it's a subset you should use string's method `rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet) -> Range<String.Index>?`. This method returns a position of a character from given set or nil if there was no character from the set present.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    print(string)
    let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789")
    return  string.rangeOfCharacter(from: allowedCharacters) != nil
}
```

However it is not a good approach to specify allowed characters as here you'll prevent user from removing characters with backspace. You should rather specify disallowed characters then this function will change to:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    print(string)
    let disallowedCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789")
    return  string.rangeOfCharacter(from: disallowedCharacters) == nil
}
```

Comment: Yep, that solved it! +1 for the extra info. One thing though: your solutions worked only if I changed `!= nil` in the first option to `== nil` and the `== nil` in the second one to `!= nil`, but still.. thnx!